# How to setup Pages admin panel dashboard template by Revox in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: web, themes, admin, panel, dashboard

I have purchased 'Pages' admin panel dashboard theme/ template which has been made by Revox.
Now how can I use it in my project? I want to use it in my ASP.NET web application.

Is there a way to use or get the project similar to the live preview?

So I can start my work by using same template as shown in the demo version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.solutionspirit.com/setup-pages-admin-template-revox/) I found amazing article which explains how to setup Pages template in your Web application